# Django sends it response to browser it gets this error: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

Tags: reactjs, django, api, frontend, django-cors-headers

I am using Django Rest Framework as my backend and ReactJS as my frontend. My DRF files look like this

settings.py

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS=['*']

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'corsheaders',
    'ecom',
    'rest_framework',
    
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
   
]

CORS_ALLOW_ALL_ORIGINS = True
```

backend/urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include


urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('ecom.urls')),
]
```

ecom/urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from ecom import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('categories/',views.CategoryList.as_view(), name = 'categories'),
    path('categories/<int:pk>/',views.CategoryDetail.as_view(), name = 'categories_detail'),
    path('products/',views.ProductList.as_view(), name = 'products'),
    path('products/<int:pk>/',views.ProductDetail.as_view(), name = 'products_detail'),
]
```

REACTJS

App.js

```
import React , {Fragment, useEffect, useState} from 'react';

import axios from 'axios';

function App() {
  const [data, setData] = useState({hits: []});
 


  useEffect(async ()=>{
    const result = await axios(
      `http://127.0.0.1:8000/categories/` ,
    );

    setData(result.data)
    });


return(
  <ul>
    {data.hits.map(item=>(
      <li key={item.id} >{item.name}</li>
    ))}
  </ul>
)



}

export default App;
```

Result

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/categories/' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/categories/ net::ERR_FAILED
```

I tested in Postman, my API response is fine. I can see my API. However, when browser tried to fetch the API, it complains by the CORS (I already installed django-cors-headers), however, I followed the documentation and tried all possible ways to get the response on the browser.

What seems to be the problem? Is it in the App.js code? I am new to React so not very confident if my frontend code is right.

I can provide more information if need.

Answer (score 0):

I tried with many ways but this was the only possible way for me to make it work.

```
CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST = (
   
    "http://127.0.0.1:8000",
    "http://localhost:3000",
    
)
```

rather than using `CORS_ALLOW_ALL_ORIGINS = True`, use `CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST` . If anyone has other question, feel free to comment. Hope it will help others as well.